# spring & WelcomeController

Tags: spring

after connected, I would like to force to forward on the action in WelcomeController
because i need get some information from user connected (Principal) and put them in session
the problem that i have is: if user try to connect by any url accessible, after connected (user+pass OK), spring re-forward automatic to this url

here is my web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>xyz</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/xyz-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xyz</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

how could i do this?
thanks a lot
best regards

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, it is done straightaway with **spring-security**.

Just integrate spring security, block access to the entire content, but leave the login page accessible to all. When a user access a secure url, the application will show the login page.

This is an example of mapping in security.xml

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_PERSON"/>  
    <form-login login-page="/login"  default-target-url="/dashboard"/>
    <logout invalidate-session="true"/>
</http>
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot some thing: after get the informations of user and put in session, i would like to re-forward to the url at first. 
Your suggestion can match this? 
thanks

Comment: default-target-url="" <- will redirect the user, at which url you want. Once the user logged in, you have that user stored in **SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()**